# Access corresponding value in PHP array given a certain known value

Tags: php, arrays

supposing I have an array like the one below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Group1
            [description] => This is the group1.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Group2
            [description] => This is group2.
        )

)
```

Supposing the title is known as "Group2". How would I able to determine using PHP its equivalent description (that is "This is group2") if it doesn't have any idea of its ,key,id, etc. only the title?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Loop through the array and check if the *title* key is **Group2**, if so simply get the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$title = "Group2";

foreach($your_array as $val){
   if($val['title'] == $title){
      echo $val['description'];
      break; //cut back on unnecessary looping
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate over the main array and scan it for that title.

Assuming your main array is called `$groups` :

```
$title = 'Group2';
foreach($groups as $key => $group){
  if ($group['title'] == $title){
    $groupDescription = $group['description'];
    // if you need to reference this group again, save it's key.
    $groupKey = $key;
  }
}
```

You can insert a `break` command after you have found the group you are looking for to terminate the loop so that it will not continue to scan the array after you have found the one you are looking for.

Comment: Do I need to add the break to yours too? :]

Comment: @nic - it all depends what the OP wants to do with the groups. I've added a note about the break command... But please don't edit other users code blocks - rather leave a comment (like you did on mine) and let the user decide whether or not they want to add it to their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
foreach($myarray as $val){
  if($val['title'] == "Group2"){
     echo 'This is description '.$val['description'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Here you need not to seperate them like key and vlaue but makesure even as value for searching